# FAQ Link farm for basic questions on DBA.SE

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

I'd like to accumulate a link farm of answers to basic SQL questions so we can put a constructve 'see the FAQ' comment on noddy questions when asked on dba.se.  Can anyone who feels so inclined add examples of n00b questions with links to answers (on SE sites or elsewhere) and I'll start curating a link farm of basic answers.

Comment: Some quite common SQL Server questions in my experience: [Simulating group_concat MySQL function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/451415/), [Removing Duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18932/), [Recovering accidentally deleted records](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/995)

Comment: In fact the [FAQ for tags on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server?sort=faq&pagesize=50) could be a good source.

Comment: I found this question and its answers helpful, even though it was closed for being too common and not needing the input of a database administrator: [What's difference between standard view and indexed view in MS SQLServer?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/14900/6173)